# How to write a lambda function that can only take in int or float pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, c++14

I need to create a lambda function that can take in either a `int *` or a `float *`, e.g., something like

```
auto func = [](void* ptr) {
  // do some assignments with the pointer
}
```

Currently, I am using the `void *` approach, but I'm wondering what are some other approaches to accomplish what I want?

I don't have access to C++17 features in my codebase so will have to stick to C++14 or lower semantics.

Comment: Probably templates of some sort.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Isn't that only available in C++20?

Comment: Typed "when were templates added to c++ into google". Response was "Templates were introduced in Release 3.0 of the language, in October 1991". I think you're OK to use templates.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm talking about templated lambdas in this case

Comment: @MadPhysicist: lol, "probably templates of some sort" is basically the answer to all C++ questions

Comment: @24n8: just to be sure: the usual case to distinguish is that you wan't to do something different with the two types ... if that is your concern, see my answer (and I guess it's that, because you use a `void *` up to now). If it is "only" about restricting the allowed input types, see the other two answers ... however, I don't quite get the use case for that.

Comment: @davidhigh. I'm not much of a C++ guy, but learning every day :)

Comment: @24n8 "Generic Lambdas" (ie, lambdas taking `auto` parameter types) were introduced in C++14. Explicit-templated lambdas were introduced in C++20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++14 has generic lambdas, meaning you can use SFINAE on them, e.g. in their trailing return types:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct valid_ptr_type : std::false_type {};
template <> struct valid_ptr_type<int *>    : std::true_type {};
template <> struct valid_ptr_type<float *>  : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> constexpr bool valid_ptr_type_v{valid_ptr_type<T>::value};

int main() {
  // only allow ptr args that fulfills
  // the valid_ptr_type_v<decltype(ptr)> trait
  auto func = [](auto *ptr) ->
      std::enable_if_t<valid_ptr_type_v<decltype(ptr)>> {
          // do stuff with ptr
      };  // note: void return type (std::enable_if default)

  int a{};
  float b{};
  char c{};
  func(&a);
  func(&b);
  // func(&c);  // error
}
```

What this does behind the hood is to constrain the deduced single template parameter of the template function call operator of the lambda's closure type.

```
// ~ish
struct AnonClosureTypeOfGenericLambda {
    template <typename T, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t<valid_ptr_type_v<decltype(T*)>>>
    void operator()(T* ptr) const { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Note that C++14 (which is within the OP's requirements) does have `std::enable_if_t`, so you don't need to use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`

Comment: should `template <> struct valid_ptr_type<char *> : std::true_type {};` be `template <> struct valid_ptr_type<float *> : std::true_type {};`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah yes I always mixup the introduction of C++17's `_v` `::value` variable template helpers with C++14's `_t` `::type` alias template helpers. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @24n8 Ah yes you asked for `float*` and `int*` only, not `char*`. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

By using the lambda overload trick:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct overload : public Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<typename... Ts> overload(Ts...)->overload<Ts...>;

auto f = overload([](int *) { /* do something with int-pointer */ }
                , [](float *){ /* do something with void-pointer */ });
```

But that's C++17. Here would be the C++11 solution:

```
template <class... Fs>
struct overload_t;

template <typename F, typename ... Fs>
struct overload_t<F, Fs...> : F, overload_t<Fs...>
{
    overload_t(F f, Fs... fs) : F(std::move(f)), overload_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...) {}

    using F::operator();
    using overload_t<Fs...>::operator();
};

template <typename F>
struct overload_t<F> : F
{
    overload_t(F f) : F(std::move(f)) {}

    using F::operator();
};

template <typename... Fs>
overload_t<Fs...> overload(Fs... fs)
{
    return overload_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...);
}
```

Comment: This leverages CTAD and thus falls short of OP’s C++14 requirement.

Comment: @dfrib: jup, just recognized that by myself and added a C++11 solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `static_assert` Has clear code and compile errors. Also, while not the question, since both types are ptrs to float or int, you can use a conditional to do a different calculation based on the actual type.

```
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    auto foo = [](auto p) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(p), float*> || std::is_same_v<decltype(p), int*>);
        if (std::is_same_v<decltype(p), int*>)
            *p = 42;
         else
            *p = 42.1f;
    };
    float f{};
    int i{};
    double d{};

    // compiles
    foo(&f);
    foo(&i);
    // doesn't compile
    //foo(&d);
}
```